# Printing only the first 5 characters of a string in one line

Tags: java, string, substring

Im trying to print just the first 5 characters of a given string in one line. My problem is the whole string is not being printed. Part of the end is being cut off.

```
  int l = 0;
      int m = 5;
      for(int i = 0; i < (string.length()/5) ; i++)
      {
            System.out.println(string.substring(j,k));
            l = m;
            m = m + 5;

      }
```

Given `string = "Hello world, my name is something which you want to"`
The result would be something like:

```
Hello
 worl
d, my
```

However, the last parts of the string is not being printed.

Comment: What are `j` and `k`..?

Comment: You need to account for the fact that at the end, you may not have exactly 5 characters...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your question what I understood is,
you need output like

```
Hello

 worl

d, my 

name 

is so

String str="Hello world, my name is something which you want to";
    for(int i=0;i<str.length();i++)
    {
        if(i%5==0 && i!=0)
        {
            System.out.println("");
        }
        System.out.print(str.charAt(i));


    }
```

Adding one more Approach

```
String str="Hello world, my name is something which you want to";
    for(int i=0,j=0;i<str.length();)
    {
        if(j<str.length() && (str.length()-j)>5)
        {j=i+5;}
        else
        {j=str.length();}
        System.out.println(str.substring(i,j));
        i+=5;
    }
```

Output:

```
Hello

 worl

d, my

 name

 is s

ometh

ing w

hich 

you w

ant t

o
```

Comment: edited for a better format,your answer works well so +1 upvote

Comment: This feels like a very roundabout solution - there are much simpler approaches, IMO. There's no need to handle it one character at a time.

Comment: Yes you are right  below one also better I think          String str="Hello world, my name is something which you want to";
  for(int i=0,j=0;i<str.length();)
  {
   if(j<str.length() && (str.length()-j)>5)
   {j=i+5;}
   else
   {j=str.length();}
   System.out.println(str.substring(i,j));
   i+=5;
  }

Answer (score 1):

> However, the last parts of the string is not being printed.

Yes, that's right - because of your loop condition. You're iterating `(string.length()/5)` times - which rounds down. So if the string has 12 characters, you'll only iterate twice... leaving out the last two letters.

I would suggest solving this slightly differently - get rid of the `l` and `m` variables (which I assume you meant to use in your `substring` call - you never declare `j` or `k`) and use the variable in the `for` loop instead. You need to make sure that you don't try to use `substring` past the end of the string though - `Math.min` is handy for that:

```
for (int sectionStart = 0; sectionStart < string.length(); sectionStart += 5) {
    int sectionEnd = Math.min(string.length(), sectionStart + 5);
    System.out.println(string.substring(sectionStart, sectionEnd);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your variables are all over the place. You have `i`, `j`, `k`, `l`, `m`; some of which are not defined in the code you present.

But you should only have one: beginning of substring, say `i`. End of substring is always 5 more: `(i + 5)`. Then increment it by 5 each loopthrough.

Answer (score 0):

Simple Recursive method

```
void test(String t){

        if(t.length() > 4){
        String o = t.substring(0,5);
        System.out.println(o);
        String x = t.substring(5,t.length());
        test(x);
        }
        else{
            System.out.println(t);
        }

    }
```

Comment: Why go recursive? I can't see any reason to do so, and it's more complicated than looping IMO.